# Auto Sum Totals in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

At the end on my Excel document I have my totals, and everything adds, but once something is sold (and is filled in red) I would like the price paid (column B) to be subtracted out of the total. What would the equation be?

Comment: You mean you want to sum a column of numbers except the ones that are coloured red?  Why not just put a sold field next to the numbers and just count those that don't have sold next to them?

Comment: More details are needed. This question does not have enough details about what you are doing for us to give a complete answer. It may be helpful to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would add another column and call it "In Inventory", then use a `SUMIF` formula to calculate your running sum. Place an "X" in the "In Inventory" column if the item is still in your available inventory, then use the `SUMIF` function with criteria being the value in the corresponding "In Inventory" cell being an "X". You can also use the value in the "In Inventory" column to automatically fill your cell red using conditional formatting. I've done this many times with great success.

Comment: instead of that I can also just sum all columns that don't have numbers in F column, as that is the sold column. If no number in F than item is not sold.

Comment: please look at comment above.